# How to convert epoch to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss linux

Tags: linux, date, epoch, strftime

I want to convert epoch like  "1444039517190" to yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss using linux?

I have tried using the following script but it gives the wrong output:

```
echo 1444039517190 | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$1) }'
```

Output:

```
47729-10-16 09:06:30
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp is not in seconds; try:

```
echo 1444039517190 | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$1/1000) }'
```

Or if you don't mind losing precision:

```
date --date=@$((1444039517190 / 1000)) +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S
```

And check if your version of [`strftime(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) support the shorter format `%F %T` instead of `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `date` directly ? You would also have to divide by 1000.

```
date -d @1444039517.190
```

Output

```
Mon Oct  5 12:05:17 CEST 2015
```